# Perfect numbers and Pell's equation

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, perfect-numbers, pell-type-equations, triangular-numbers

(**Disclaimer: The following is a naive attempt to apply the theory of Pell's equations to perfect numbers.  Please bear in mind that this is my **first time** to try solving such an equation.**)

Let $p^k$ be a **nontrivial** prime power satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  (That is, we require $k > 1$.)

Suppose that $M = 2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)$ is an [even perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Even_perfect_numbers).  By the Euclid-Euler Theorem, $2^t - 1$ (and therefore $t$) must be prime.  (If $t$ is prime, it does not necessarily follow that $2^t - 1$ is also prime.)

Here is my:

**INITIAL QUESTION**

> Is $M(2p^k - 1) + p^{2k}$ a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let
$$T = M(2p^k - 1) + p^{2k}.$$
Then $T$ is triangular if and only if
$$1 + 8T = S^2.$$
Suppose to the contrary that $T = U^2$ is also a square.  It follows that $M > 6$, because otherwise when $M = 6$, we obtain
$$M(2p^k - 1) + p^{2k} \equiv 2\cdot(2\cdot{1} - 1) + 1^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$$
Then we obtain the [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)
$$S^2 - 8U^2 = 1.$$
This has fundamental solution $(S,U)=(3,1)$.  However, we also know that
$$T = 2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)(2p^k - 1) + p^{2k}$$
which appears not to split into terms linear in $2^{t-1}$, $2^t - 1$ and $p^k$, for $t \geq 3$ and $k > 1$, at least per [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor+completely+2%5E%7Bt-1%7D%282%5Et+-+1%29%282p%5Ek+-+1%29+%2B+p%5E%7B2k%7D).

This hints that $T$ may not be a square, hence the theory of Pell's equations may not apply.  (Note that the lowest possible value of $T$ is $9803119 = {47} \times {208577}$, which is **not triangular**. Hence I am led to believe that, in general, $T$ may, in fact, **neither be triangular nor a square**.)

**FINAL QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Does my proof for showing that $T$ is **not** a [square triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number) suffice?  If the proof is not logically correct, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

> **(2)** Would it then be possible to (unconditionally) show that $M(2p^k - 1) + p^{2k}$ is not triangular?

Comment: Just to clarify : Do you want to show that $T$ , no matter which even perfect number and which prime power satisfying the above conditions we choose, can be a square or a triangular number , let alone both ?

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for your time and attention.  Yes, I want to initially check whether $T$ is a square triangular number.  This amounts to checking a Pell's equation, for which I am still a beginner/novice.  If $T$ is not a square triangular number, then does that mean that $T$ is neither a square number nor a triangular number?  That is essentially what I am asking for in the question.

Comment: @Peter:  And to answer your request for clarification - Yes, $M > 6$ is an **arbitrary even perfect number**, while $p^k$ is an **arbitrary nontrivial prime power** with $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: I could not find any example (not even with $M=6$) for which $T$ is a square or a triangular number. Both properties seem to be not realizable. I have however no idea for a proof , not even for the square-case.

Comment: @Peter:  Up to what numerical limit did you do your search for examples?  Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: I have not yet systematically searched , but an example must be rather big. If you are interested in concrete search ranges, I can systematically search and post a PARI/GP routine as a partial answer.

Comment: Yes, please do so, @Peter.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've just got a proof that for $T$ to be a square, it is necessary that $$p^k\le  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)-1$$ If you are interested in the proof, then I'll write it. This necessary condition may help searching since it is guaranteed that if $p^k\gt  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)-1$, then $T$ cannot be a square.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I would appreciate a proof for your assertion.  I look forward to it.  Cheers! --- (Arnie Dris)

Comment: Concerning the square solutions : For every given $M$, we can find all integer solutions (not only the prime powers) of $M(2P-1)+P^2=X^2$ , if we can factor $M+1$. This way, I could verify that upto exponent $89$, we can rule out perfect squares with the given condition $p\equiv k\equiv 1\mod 4$ and $k>1$. For the triangle numbers, I did not find yet such a method.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: The following PARI/GP routine searches for examples:

```
gp > forprime(q=1,1000,if(isprime(2^q-1,2)==1,s=(2^q-1)*2^(q-1);forprime(p=1,10^8,if(Mod(p,4)==1,forstep(k=1,30,4,t=s*(2*p^k-1)+p^(2*k);if(issquare(t)+issquare(8*t+1)>0,print([s,p,k,t,factor(t)])))))))
[496, 5, 1, 4489, Mat([67, 2])]
[496, 1733, 1, 4721929, [41, 2; 53, 2]]
[8128, 16510001, 1, 272848519588129, [157, 2; 105211, 2]]
gp >
```

For all solutions in this range, we have $\ k=1\ $ (which is however ruled out). Hence this first range shows that for a solution, we must have at least one of $\ M>10^{769}\ $ , $\ p>10^8\ $ , $\ k>30\ $

```
gp > forprime(q=1,1000,if(isprime(2^q-1,2)==1,s=(2^q-1)*2^(q-1);forprime(p=1,10^4,if(Mod(p,4)==1,forstep(k=1,4000,4,t=s*(2*p^k-1)+p^(2*k);if(issquare(t)+issquare(8*t+1)>0,print([s,p,k,t,factor(t)])))))))
[496, 5, 1, 4489, Mat([67, 2])]
[496, 1733, 1, 4721929, [41, 2; 53, 2]]
gp >
```

This second search range also reveals no solutions and shows that we must have at least one of $\ M>10^{769}$ , $\ p>10^4\ $ , $\ k>4\ 000\ $

I will further examine the $\ k=5\ $-case. Since $\ p>10^8\ $ is established, we know that a solution must exceed $\ 10^{40}\ $ making it unlikely that there is one.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @Peter!  An upvote for now.  (I hope you do not mind my grammar and spelling edits.)  =)

Comment: Edits that improve the post are always welcome (in particular typos or other errors). If $k=5$ and $M<10^{769}$ , then $p>10^9$. I currently run the range $10^9-10^{10}$ in this case.

Comment: I marvel at your coding expertise, @Peter!  Are you using some advanced packages / code routines for Pari-GP?  Additionally, is it possible to install Pari-GP locally, say to a desktop PC with an Intel Core i5 processor and 8 gigabytes of RAM?  Please advise!

Comment: No, all the functions are already built-in. Downloading the (free) PARI-tool should be no problem. It even runs on the problematic new windows versions. You might also be interested in yafu (for integer factorization) and PFGW (for primality tests) , both also free and running on most machines.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to those resources, @Peter!  I will check them out.  =)

Comment: $10^{10}$ range finished (with $k=5$ and $M<10^{769}$). No solutions. Hence, we can replace $10^9$ by $10^{10}$. I will think about how we can prove that there are in fact no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long to comment* :

For $T$ to be a square, it is necessary that
$$p^k\leqslant  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)-1$$

*Proof* :

Since $T$ can be written as
$$T = \bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)\bigg)^2-2^{t-1}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)+1\bigg) $$
one can see that
$$T\lt \bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)\bigg)^2$$
holds.

So, one can see that **if**
$$\bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)-1\bigg)^2\lt T\tag1$$
holds, **then** since
$$\bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)-1\bigg)^2\lt T\lt \bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)\bigg)^2\tag2$$
holds, $T$ cannot be a square.

Now, $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{align}&2^{t-1}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)+1\bigg)\lt 2\bigg(p^k+2^{t-1}(2^t - 1)\bigg)-1
\\\\&\iff 2p^k\gt  2^{t-1}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)+1
\\\\&\iff 2p^k\geqslant  2^{t-1}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)+2
\\\\&\iff p^k\geqslant  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)+1\tag3\end{align}$$

In short, **if** $(3)$ holds, **then** since $(2)$ holds, $T$ cannot be a square.

Therefore, for $T$ to be a square, it is necessary that
$$p^k\lt  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)+1\tag4$$

Since the both sides of $(4)$ are odd, $(4)$ is equivalent to
$$p^k\leqslant  2^{t-2}(2^t-1)\bigg(2^{t-1}(2^t-1)-1\bigg)-1\ .\quad\blacksquare$$

Comment: An upvote for now, @mathlove.  Thank you for your time and attention!  =)