# $T_U - T_V$ is not triangular when $U = V+2$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, triangular-numbers

This question is a follow-up to [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375859).

**Edit: (Updated (in response to [this comment from mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375878/t-u-t-v-is-not-triangular-when-u-v2?noredirect=1#comment9144387_4375878) - February 07, 2022 - 12:50 PM Manila time) It appears that we need the extra condition that $U$ is prime.**

---

**Edit: (Updated (in response to [this comment from mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375878/t-u-t-v-is-not-triangular-when-u-v2?noredirect=1#comment9144398_4375878) - February 07, 2022 - 01:08 PM Manila time) $U = 11$ is a counterexample, if we restrict $U$ to primes.  I have asked mathlove to consider the case of  a Mersenne prime $U = 2^t - 1$.**

Let $U$ and $V$ be positive integers such that $U = V + 2$.

Here is my:

**QUESTION**

> Can the positive integer
> $$T := T_U - T_V$$
> be a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where
> $$T_X := \frac{X(X+1)}{2}$$
> is the $X^{\text{th}}$ triangular number?

**MY ATTEMPT #1**

Plugging in $V = U - 2$ into the formula for $T$ and simplifying, we obtain
$$T = \frac{U(U+1)}{2} - \frac{(U-2)(U-1)}{2} = 2U - 1.$$
Consequently, we obtain
$$T \text{ is triangular } \iff 1 + 8T \text{ is a square, call it } S^2$$
$$\iff 1 + 8T = 1 + 8(2U - 1) = 16U - 7 = S^2.$$
The last equation implies that $S^2 \equiv 9 \mod {16}$.  This is where I get stuck, as I do not currently know how to use the assumption that $U$ is a Mersenne prime to get a contradiction.

**MY ATTEMPT #2**

Since $U = 2^t - 1$ is a Mersenne prime, then
$$U \equiv
\begin{cases}
{
3 \pmod {16}, t = 2 \\
7 \pmod {16}, t = 3 \\
15 \pmod {16}, t \geq 5. \\
}
\end{cases}
$$

Consequently,
$$16U - 7 \equiv
\begin{cases}
{
({16}\cdot{3}) - 7 \equiv 9 \pmod {16}, t = 2 \\
({16}\cdot{7}) - 7 \equiv 9 \pmod {16}, t = 3 \\
({16}\cdot{15}) - 7 \equiv 9 \pmod {16}, t \geq 5, \\
}
\end{cases}
$$
whence we do not arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: No, it isn't. $T_U - T_{U-2}$ can be a triangular number. Take $U=8$.

Comment: I forgot the condition that $U$ must be prime.  My apologies, @mathlove!  (Please do not delete your comment, by the way, as it adds context to the original question.)  Thank you.

Comment: Then, take $U=11$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for providing that counterexample, @mathlove!  Do you have a counterexample for the case when $U$ is a *Mersenne prime*?

Comment: Then, take $U=127$.

Comment: My profuse thanks for providing that counterexample, @mathlove!  Please flesh out and consolidate all of your three comments into a single answer, so that I can upvote and then accept it.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_U - T_{U-2}$ can be a triangular number.

- For $U=8$, one has $T_8-T_6=T_5$.
- For $U=11$ which is prime, one has $T_{11}-T_9=T_6$.
- For $U=127$ which is a Mersenne prime, one has $T_{127}-T_{125}=T_{22}$.